# VS code not showing References for JS functions that are imported in Vue files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vscode-extensions

I have a Vue component and a Javascript files as follows.

Test.vue

[image]

test.js

[image]

As shown in the Screenshot, VS code show the reference of the `testFunc` function in the Vue component, but in the test.js file, `testFunc` shows 0 references. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the `Vuter` plugin. I removed that and installed the [`Volar`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MisterJ.vue-volar-extention-pack) plugin and it worked.

Comment: I still have this issue without Vuter. Does this solution only work with Vue2?

Comment: I haven't tried this with vue 3.